# Getting unsupported shape type 957 error when uploading shapefiles using Cypress testing with ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, cypress, shapefile

I can successfully upload `.dbf`, `.prj`, `.shx` and `.shp` files generating shapefile in ReactJs. No error, the request goes through smoothly. The issue comes when I'm writing a test in Cypress and I get the following:

```
Error: unsupported shape type: 957
    at new Shp (VM86 bundle.js:101829:33)
    at VM86 bundle.js:101822:12
    at async Promise.all (:4200/__/index 0)
    at async generateShape (VM86 bundle.js:1929:18)
    at async uploadShapeFileToServer (VM86 bundle.js:2040:31)
    at async onSubmit (VM86 bundle.js:1343:13)
    at async VM86 bundle.js:114661:9
```

If I delete `.shp` the error is gone but I wont be able to generate shapefile without it. If I drag and drop the files manually in the E2E Cypress browser (Chrome) and click upload then it works perfectly and the upload is successful with all 4 files without error. Is it something with Cypress test? I can't really find any help.

```
Update: 
When I upload manually (and it's successful) then the size of the file is different when Cypress uploads it.
```

The test command when it fails:

```
layout.createShapeFileFormItems.formInputs.getDragAndDrop().should("exist").attachFile(files, {subjectType: "drag-n-drop"});

layout.createShapeFileFormItems.getUploadButton().click({multiple: true});


getDragAndDrop: () => cy.get("#fileUpload input[type=file]")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved**:

If anybody runs into the same issue I made it work with with specifying `filePath` and `encoding`.

```
cy.get('input[type=file]')
    .attachFile({ filePath: './files/example.shp', encoding: "binary" })
```

Answer (score 2):

If you target the input element directly (as you have), the `subjectType` should be `input`.

Type `drag-n-drop` is for the scenario where the `<input>` is hidden and contained within another visible element that the user uses as drop-target.

Try changing the the subjectType in the first instance.

But I suspect there is some attribute missing on the upload call. You can check the call when manually executed vs the call when Cypress executes for any difference (perhaps in the headers).

Comment: thank you for your replay. I tried `subjectType: "input"` before I posted my question and I was getting the same issue. I will check the second part of your answer suggestion.